# Access query to make column that shows checkbox for Yes/No column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've written a query to create a table in MS-access:

```
CREATE TABLE [customers]
([id] NUMBER, [authorised] YESNO);
```

This works fine. However the YES/NO column displays -1 and 0, when I'd really rather a checkbox.

Is there any way to do this within the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug: [ACC2002: Make-Table Query Does Not Format Yes/No or Bit Fields Correctly](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279150/en-us). The Knowledge Base article proposes two workarounds, unfortunately none of them one can use in a query.

Comment: This is not a "Make-Table" query, but a DDL CREATE TABLE statement. The reason there is no SQL-based solution is that a checkbox is a presentation-level issue, and SQL doesn't deal with presentation at all. One should not expect to be able to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you need to do in a production app (i.e., execute DDL to create a new table), I would suggest that you might be better off using a table template, instead. That way, you can set up the template table with all the presentation-level properties set, and then copy it to the final destination.

Of course, now that I've written that, I Googled a bit, and it is, in fact, possible do to this in DAO:

[How to Programmatically Specify the Display Control for a Field](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304274)

I'm not certain, but from the code, it looks like you could run your DDL to create the table, and then run DAO code to alter the display type of the one field, but you'd have to test that to be sure. It might be that you have to create the table entirely in DAO (but it doesn't look like it from the code in the cited article).