# How to add a Yes/No Column Into an Access 2007 Select Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a linked table called `[Part Number]` and locally, users need to be able to select a check box (Yes/No) field corresponding to the part number to perform actions on it with other commands. Currently, to have the check box in the displayed query, I have a separate local table that maintains a list of all of the part numbers in `[Part Number]` that pairs them with a check box that is then rolled into the displayed query. What I would like to do is have a query that just directly queries `[Part Number]` and adds it's own Yes/No field to get rid of the table that has to be constantly updated to make sure all part numbers are accounted for.

I know this is possible for text fields:

```
SELECT 
 [Part Number].Concatenate, 
 [Part Number].[Part Nbr] & " " & Date() AS [Select] 
FROM [Part Number];
```

A field called "Select" will be added to the query with the part number and the date next to it. I want that field to be a `Yes/No` field.

Edit:

I don't want the `[Part Number]` table to have the Yes/No field on it because it is shared between multiple users and will interfere with actions the database takes based on selections. I also would like to not use a table at all since the parts list changes frequently and the front end table would have to be constantly be getting updated from the back end table `[Part Number]` to ensure everything works properly. Having a select query based on the `[Part Number]` table would automatically update every time the parts list changes since it's a query, not a table. This query would be rolled into the displayed query that ties together several tables and queries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access query to make column that shows checkbox for Yes/No column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744629/access-query-to-make-column-that-shows-checkbox-for-yes-no-column)

Comment: You can't create an editable checkbox from a calculated field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DonJewett said, this is not possible for Yes/No checkbox fields. Your best bet is to do it the way you are doing; it's easiest to just clear the Yes/No table and repopulate it every time you open the form.

(on `Form_Load()` of your selection form, `frmMultiSelect`):

```
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblNodes")

    'Clear current links
    strSQL = "DELETE * FROM tblMultiSelect"
    db.Execute strSQL

    'Create '0' state links for every node in tblNodes
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblMultiSelect(node_id, selected) "
        strSQL = strSQL & "VALUES (" & rs![node_id] & ", 0);"

        db.Execute strSQL
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    'Update subform
    Me.frmMultiSelect.Requery
```

Comment: Damn, that would have been too easy... At least I have something that works even if it's not as simple as I wish it could be.

Comment: I spent a while trying to get it to work for something I built a few weeks back without success. In the end, however, I decided that I actually quite like the way this method works. Avoids the use of calculated fields, and it's very simple in operation.